# TransactionSynchronizationManager and Detection Of Transaction Rollback

Tags: spring-transactions

I am adding some code that executes in the beforeCommit() and beforeCompletion() methods of a TransactionSycnhoniztion in Spring. I need to be able to detect in a transaction is active and marked for rollback before executing my code..

```
public void beforeCompletion() {
    if (transaction inactive and not rolledback)
        doit();
}
```

How do I detect if transaction is active and not rolled back?. I see the method isActualTransactionActive() but can see no way to access the transaction or determine if rolled back. (unless those methods arent called if the transaction is rolled back)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through the Spring source code and AbstractPlatformTransactionManager has methods for processCommit() and processRollback().....

processCommit() calls triggerBeforeCommit() and processRollback does not.

So the answer is beforeCommit() isnt called when a rollback happens....

and beforeCompletion is called in both cases but passes status in the method argument.